# Using Newtonsoft.Json in a TFS release definition from powershell

Tags: json, powershell, tfs, json.net, devops

Folks,

We are using TFS 2017 on-premise and are working toward provisioning/deploying to an Azure website and database. Our Azure database provisioning/updating task works well, but until we can automate the website portion part, we have an interim step where we copy the web package from the build into a staging share.

This step runs on a Deployment Group under the TFS vstsagent as follows:

1. Create the temp folder
2. Expand the zip file into the temp folder
3. Retrieve the Out folder under the expanded zip file
4. Move out folder to root of temp folder
5. Merge the appsettings.json file with the master.appsettings.json file for the environment.
6. Re-zip the web package
7. Copy the web package to staging destination share under PRJ\build#

Step 5) is performed using the merge feature of Newtonsoft.Json.

```
# Load the Newtonsoft.Json dll
$asmNewtonsoftJson = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile([io.path]::combine($FolderToZip, "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"))

# Read the appsettings.json file and store as a JObject
$appSettingsPath = [io.path]::combine($folderToZip, "appsettings.json")
$appSettingsJson = (Get-Content $appSettingsPath | Out-String)
$appSettings = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($appSettingsJson)

# Read the master appsettings.json file from the env and store as a JObject
$appSettingsMasterPath = [io.path]::combine($AppSettingsMasterFolderPath, $Environment + ".appsettings.json")
$appSettingsMasterJson = (Get-Content $appSettingsMasterPath | Out-String)
$appSettingsMaster = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($appSettingsMasterJson)

# Merge the master appsettings.json file into the appsettings.json file
$jms = New-Object Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JsonMergeSettings
$jms.MergeArrayHandling = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.MergeArrayHandling]::Merge
$appSettings.Merge($appSettingsMaster, $jms)

# Write out the updated appsettings.json file
[io.File]::WriteAllText($appSettingsPath, $appSettings.ToString())
```

Note: $folderToZip contains the expanded contents of the web package. This also contains the Newtonsoft.Json dll (and presumably its dependencies).

The above code works fine in the Windows Powershell ISE app, but fails when run in the TFS release definition task.

It fails at step 5) with the following error:

```
2018-10-11T19:29:39.1790546Z ##[error]Unable to find type  [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject].
At C:\vstsagent\A1\_work\r7\a\<path>\drop\Build\mymergescript.ps1:84 char:20
$appSettings = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($appSettings)
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

It appears that the Newtonsoft.Json.dll isn't getting loaded properly when deployed by the TFS vstsagent.

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Have you referenced the `Newtonsoft.Json` in your project and restored the package during building?

Comment: It turns out that the newtonsoft.json assembly failed to load because it couldn't load netstandard.  Powershell on this machine was using dotnet 2.1.105. My dev box (which this script worked) was using dotnet 2.1.401.  I updated dotnet version to 2.1.403 by installing the latest skd on the failed machine and the script ran.

Comment: Btw, to track down the load issue, I used changed the load the code above to

    # Load the Newtonsoft.Json dll
    $asmNewtonsoftJsonPath = [io.path]::combine($PSScriptRoot, "Newtonsoft.Json.dll")    
    Add-Type -Path $asmNewtonsoftJsonPath
inside a try catch block and caught the following exception:
    } catch [System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException] {
        Write-Host "Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        Write-Host "StackTrace: $($_.Exception.StackTrace)"
        Write-Host "LoaderExceptions: $($_.Exception.LoaderExceptions)"
    }

Comment: Sorry about the lack of code formatting above.